# If 'a' is a natural number and 'b' is a digit such that $(3a+2007)^2=4b85924$, then find $a-b$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If 'a' is a natural number and 'b' is a digit such that $(3a+2007)^2=4b85924$, then find $a-b$.
All that i could figure out is that the ones digit of 'a' can have $2$ or $8$ in it.

Answer (score 7):

Since $(3a+2007)^2$ is divisible by $9$, we see that $4b85924$ has to be divisible by $9$.

So, $4+b+8+5+9+2+4=32+b$ has to be divisible by $9$.

It follows from this that $b=4,a=37$.

---

After knowing $b=4$, one way to find $a$ is as follows :

Since the right-most digit of $3a$ is either $1$ or $5$, the right-most digit of $a$ is either $5$ or $7$.

The right-most two digits of $(3a+2007)^2$ are $84,84,04,64,24,44,44,24$ for $a=5,7,15,17,25,27,35,37$ respectively.

The right-most three digits of $(3\times 25+2007)^2$ is $724$. So, $a=37$.

Comment: How is $(3a+2007)^2$ is divisible by 9 ?

Comment: @Harshit $(3a+2007)^2 = (3(a + 669))^2 = 9(a + 669)^2$

Comment: How is the value of $a$ determined ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the hard way:

$(3a + 2007)^2 = 4b85924$

$9a^2 + 2*3*2007a = 4b85924 - 2007^2 = 4b85924 -4028049= b57875$

$9a(a + 1338)= b57875$

$a(a+1338)=\frac {b57875}9 = \frac {b*100000}9 + \frac{57875}9$

$=\frac {99999*b}9+\frac b9 + 6430 + \frac 59 = 11111b+ 6430 + \frac {5+b}9\in \mathbb Z$

So $b = 4$.

$(3a + 2007)^2 = 4485924$

$3a + 2007 = \pm \sqrt{4485924} = \pm 2118$

$3a = -4125, 111$

$a = -1375, 37$ as $a\in \mathbb N$, $a =37 and $a-b = 33$.

.....

Easy way:

$2+7 = 9$ so $9|2007$.  $(3a + 2007)^2 = 9a^2 + 6*2007a + 2007^2$ so $9|9a^2$ and $9|6*2007a$ and $9|2007^2$ so $9|4b85924$ so $9|b + 4+8+5+9+2+4=b+32$ so $9|b + 3+2 = b+5$ so $b+5 = 9$ and $b=4$

$(3a + 2007)^2 = 4485924$ etc.